# Custom button cloning issue

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have logic on my controller that it should clone few fields only. I want to clone only those fields that are not in `cloneaccount` custom settings. below controller clones everything.

Also, we have workflow rules that sends out an email as soon as record is created. I want email to only go out when I hit save. not when i hit clone.
Please let me know what's wrong with the below controller:

```
public with sharing class AccountController {

public Account objAccount {get;set;}        
public string AccountID;                        
  set<String> setExFields = new set<String>();
private Account objNewAccount;
 Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> mapAccountFields;

public AccountController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
{

 }              
          public PageReference autoRun()
 {
    AccountID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

    if(AccountID != null)

    {        mapAccountFields = Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.getMap() ;



    List<CloneAccount__c > Exfields = Cloneaccount__c.getall().values();

        for( Cloneaccount__c excludedField: ExFields){
            setExFields.add(excludedField.Name.toLowerCase());
        }

        for(String s: mapAccountFields.keyset()){
            if(!setExFields.contains(s)){
                if(queryString == ''){
                    queryString += s;
                }else{
                    queryString += ',' + s;
                }
            }
        }

            objnewaccount = Database.Query('Select ' + queryString + ' From account where id= \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(accountID) + '\'');   

            objAccount = objNewAccount.clone(false,true,false,false);

    //     insert objaccount;

   PageReference cloneaccount = new PageReference('/'+objaccount.id+'/e?clone=1');
    cloneaccount.setRedirect(true);
    return accountPage;
}
return null;
}

}
```

Comment: SFSE etiquette discourages use of exhortations. A look back at SFSE history shows that well-worded, well-formed questions get extremely rapid response from the community, no encouragement required.

Comment: And a side note, using multiple punctuations in a row (e.g. `...`, `???`, `!!!`) is generally considered rude.

Comment: Thanks Adrian for the note.i will keep this is in mind.could you please help to resolve my issue

Comment: I'm wondering if perhaps you're using the field's `label` instead of the `API name`. In your custom setting of fields to exclude, do you have any custom fields? If so, do their `Name` values end with `__c`?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attempting to accomplish some conflicting goals:

1. Only clone some fields, excluding ones from a predefined list
2. Use the standard Salesforce edit/clone page to allow users to modify the data (on the cloned record)
3. Wait to insert the cloned record until the user clicks the 'Save' button on the standard Salesforce edit page
4. Send an email after the clone has been inserted

Goals #1 and #2 are, to the best of my knowledge, mutually exclusive. More specifically, I don't believe it's possible to alter the behavior of the standard clone page without overriding it. Using the standard clone page means that you will see all of the populated fields be carried over.

To do exactly what you want, you'd need to use Visualforce instead of being able to rely on the standard edit/clone page.

Using `<apex:detail inlineedit="true">` could usually assist you here, but it requires the `subject="<Salesforce record Id Here>"` attribute as well. To use that, you would need to insert the cloned record (so it is given an Id) before editing it, which conflicts with goal #3.

Probably the best you'll be able to do is to add a new field to help control your workflow rule(s), modify your workflow rule(s), and modify the trigger for `Account`.

- Create a new checkbox field, 'delay_email', default to false
- Change the workflow to evaluate on insert and every time the record is edited to subsequently meet criteria
- Update the workflow criteria to include `delay_email__c != true`
- Modify the trigger (before update) and set `delay_email__c = false;`

This should keep the workflow working the same as it is now for records not being (partially) cloned.

Then, update your controller to set `objAccount.delay_email__c = true;` before inserting.

Then you can redirect to the standard edit page for the partially cloned record (since it now has an Id).

Saving the record will cause the trigger to unset the delay field on the first update, which will cause the record to satisfy the workflow criteria for sending the email. This approach may not work if you have other workflow field updates that occur after the record is inserted.

Beyond that, I'm not really sure that a Custom Setting is the best tool for the job here. I'd suggest taking a look at fieldsets. They can be managed with clicks (instead of code), and are metadata (meaning that they can be deployed between orgs). It'd also take most of the guesswork out of building your query string.

There's also a neat little pattern you can use for building the string of fields to query.

I'll wrap this up with an example integrating both the changes required to your controller for my scheme, and using a fieldset to build the dynamic SOQL. Assuming your fieldset is called `ExcludeFromClone`:

```
public PageReference autoRun(){
    AccountID = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

    if(AccountID != null){
        mapAccountFields = Schema.SObjectType.Account.fields.getMap() ;

        Set<String> ExFields = new Set<String>();

        for(Schema.FieldSetMember fsm: SObjectType.Account.fieldSets.ExcludeFromClone.getFields()){
            ExFields.add(fsm.getFieldPath());
        }

        Set<String> allFields = new Set<String>(mapAccountFields.values());
        allFields.removeAll(ExFields);
        String fieldsToQuery = String.join(new List<String>(allFields), ', ');

        objnewaccount = Database.Query('Select ' + queryString + ' From account where id= \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(accountID) + '\'');   

        objAccount = objNewAccount.clone(false,true,false,false);
        objAccount.delay_email__c = true;
        insert objaccount;

        PageReference cloneaccount = new PageReference('/'+objaccount.id+'/e');
        cloneaccount.setRedirect(true);
        return accountPage;
    }
    return null;
}
```